# How to stop sync file when using dropbox(not pause and resume, I want to quit)

Tags: macos, sync, dropbox, finder

I am trying to upload an file to dropbox, but it takes over 8hrs.
So I want to quit and place my file back.
However, I can see only 'resume' and 'pause', no 'quit':<

I already tried shutdown dropbox program, but after did that I can not find my original file in finder.(I am OSX User)

How can I retrieve my file to finder?
Thanks in advanced:D

Comment: So you still see your file in the finder right?

Comment: @c0dev nope. I can not see my file in finder. and dropbox process bar still shows "Syncing "fileName" (8 hrs left)".